# C++ selection sort - insert method and private variables

Tags: c++, private-members

I'm in the process of writing a program for selection sort. I just posted something regarding std::vector, however this post is on a different subject.

I was able to compile the program, however it was running into run-time error when insert() was invoked in the main method.

My ArrayS has the code below as a copy constructor and also to initialize nElems to 0 when ArrayS is created.

[ArrayS.cpp]

```
ArrayS::ArrayS(int max)
{
    std::vector<long> a;                 
    nElems = 0; 
}

void ArrayS::insert(long value)    // put element into array
      {
      a[nElems] = value;             // insert it
      nElems++;                      // increment size
      }
```

[ArrayS.h]

```
private:

std::vector<long> a;

int nElems;
```

Now, do I need get/set method in the ArrayS.cpp to manipulate nElems? I'm not sure how in C++ you work with private variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors keep track of their size. And to be efficient, `a[nElems]` will assume that your `vector` is large enough to accommodate that access.

It looks like you want:

```
void ArrayS::insert(long value)    // put element into array
      {
      a.push_back(value);             // insert it AND increment size
      }
```

It also looks like you can disregard `nElems`.  If you want the vector's size, just call `a.size()`.

Comment: So I can totally disregard "nElems?" Also, does std::vector change the nature of my program?

Comment: So, using std::vector, it is not necessary to have "insert" method in my program, correct? Since I'll just use "push_back" instead of insert() ?

Comment: @SndLt Since, `a` is `private`, only member functions can access it.  That's a good thing, since you can control how it's accessed.  See my edit.